# When the Gemoro answers the question לאתויי מאי is the answer complete or an example?

Tags: words, talmud-gemara

BACKGROUND

A Mishnah may list a number of items and then follow with a general statement. 
For example in [Shabbos 12 (4)](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Shabbat.12?lang=en&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) the Mishnah says

> הכותב שתי אותיות בהעלם אחד - חיב. כתב בדיו, בסם, בסקרא, בקומוס
>   ובקנקנתום, **ובכל דבר שהוא רושם**
>
> [If] one writes two letters under one spell of unawareness, he is
>   liable. He is liable if he writes in ink, or Sikra [an orange earth],
>   or resin, or Kankantom [a copper based paint], **or any substance that
>   leaves a mark.**

On the general statement  "ובכל דבר שהוא רושם or any substance that leaves a mark", the Gemoro asks "לאתויי מאי/what does this statement include" and answers that it includes the items mentioned in a Beraiso of Rabbi Chananiah. The Gemoro brings another  Beraiso of Rabbi Chiyo to include further items.

QUESTION

When a mishnah makes a general statement following a list and the Gemoro asks what does this general statement include, does it include only the listed items in the answer or does it include anything like those items?

Comment: What you are really asking I suppose is to bring some proof from rishonim who add on more items, what the g'moro doesnt mention.  I think you  will find this quite often.  @Avrohom Yitzchok.

Comment: @newcomer Thank you for the useful clarification.